# Qt 5 OpenGL binding textures causing werid bug

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures

I'm using a Qt Creator (C++) and I'm creating a GLWidget. I need to use a few textures. The simplest way to do this in Qt is using QGLWidget function *bindTexture(QImage)*. When I'm trying to bind textures using this method my QGLWidget is acting weirdly - it's showing nothing (even though I'm calling *updateGL()* many times) but its clear color. It starts working properly when I add an item with one of previously binded textures. This is how I'm initialiazing textures:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::white);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    generateGrid(0.025);

    //**deleting lines below solves this problem... but then I can't use textures!**
    mvTextureID.push_back(bindTexture(QImage("and.png")));
    mvRedTextureID.push_back(bindTexture(QImage("and_red.png")));
    mvTextureID.push_back(bindTexture(QImage("nand.png")));
    mvRedTextureID.push_back(bindTexture(QImage("nand_red.png")));

}
```

Am I misusing method bindTexture? Why do I have to actually use one of the binded textures before my GLWidget starts acting as it should?

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake - the problem is that I was using function (which I didn't need at that point) `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` at the beginning and I wasn't disabling it until the first textured object was created. Also these two functions are unnecessary

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEARES
```

since Qt's `bindTexture();` is calling them itself.